# "no such file to load -- sqlite3" but sqlite is installed [Ubuntu 14]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to get an old RoR site running on a new server. I've installed everything and all the gems but when I try ruby script/server I get an error and in the error log it states:

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  no such file to load -- sqlite3
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
```

... full stack here: http://pastie.org/private/2iihmg58uyalqyg3xsp80a ...

I've tried re-installing the sqlite3 gem with the optional:

```
--with-sqlite3-dir=/usr/bin
```

Which I believe is the correct location of my sqlite installation.

I can't work out what else I can do to get this working, any pointers?

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install sqlite3`

Comment: I get: sqlite3 is already the newest version.